# What are the advantages of using unordered lists in nav bars?

Tags: html, css, navigation

I have seen several tutorials explaining how to create a nav bar, and they all went ahead by first adding an unordered list, then removing the standard style of it and the list items (in particular the bullet points and the margins). Is there an advantage to using lists instead of just using `a` elements or `span` elements directly which don't have any style which needs to be removed?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/navigation-in-lists-to-be-or-not-to-be/ Read the comments.

Comment: @FluffyKitten You changed the title of my question without consent. You thereby actually changed the meaning of my question. Perhaps this also led people to the conclusion that my question is opinion-based. "Thanks?"

Comment: Your original question was already closed as opinion-based, so I edited it to try get it *reopened*. I edited it to focus on the fact-based parts (such as asking if there are advantages), so that it meets SO guidelines. The opinion-based part was why people do things - to answer  that we have to make assumptions about their reasoning, which would be based on opinions. FYI edits on questions and answers on SO do not require consent of the author - it is recommended practice to edit posts if it improves them or helps them meet the guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always markup a page based on the purpose (or semantics) of the elements and then style for the appearance.

- Alternative containers such as for example **divs have no semantic meaning** and can group any unrelated elements - they offer no clue to what the contents, how they are related and what purpose they might serve. **Lists indicate an inherent relationship** between the elements as more than just a random collection of items.
- **Logically (and even visually) a navigation menu *is* a list of links** - whether they are displayed horizontally or vertically, they are still a list of related items. The default styling for a list is not always suitable for every type of list, but that doesn't mean that the list *element* isn't suitable.
- Lists allow for **hierarchy to be easily defined for sub-menus** (and sub-sub-menus etc) - this is a huge advantage of using lists for navs. This is because of the inherent relationship, as well as the ability to have a list item that contains other full list.
- It also allows for **better accessibility**, as keyboard navigation and screen readers an recognise this relationship more easily and offer much more effective navigation through the list.